# Which limitations are in doing work in background?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

As I know Android allows to start periodically services once per 15 minutes and maximum time of doing work in background is 10 minutes in Doze mode, but I think the code bellow avoid this limitation. Am I right?

```
public class TestWorker extends Worker {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public WorkerResult doWork() {
            new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doPeriodicalyWork();
                }
            }, 0, 5000);
            return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> As I know Android allows to start periodically services once per 15 minutes

Yes, correct.

> and maximum time of doing work in background is 10 minutes in Doze mode

Although I don't think I've seen it documented, I think this is about right, yes.

> I think the code bellow avoid this limitation. Am I right?

Honestly, I don't see the reason why it would avoid the limitation. If the device is already in the Doze mode, `doPeriodicallyWork()` simply will not be executed because the CPU will be sleeping. Wake locks are not allowed. It will only run during maintenance windows when the job scheduler, which holds the timer, is up.

The best way to figure this out is, of course, to try it out and test it. But I will be very surprised if you make it work. If so, it's worth filing a bug for Google :)

So, I think instead of trying to hack Android, you should focus on the root of the problem instead. Why do you need to do this in the first place? These limitations are not there for bothering Android developers, they are to save users from the developers which don't respect user's phone resources.

Comment: I have tested it manually enabled Doze mode and timer works continuously ). I want to run every 15 minutes service that run scheduler that tick every 5 seconds and getting info about phone and then sleep after 10 minutes

Comment: This doesn't sound like you are bypassing the limitation unless I'm missing something. Every 15 minutes you run a 10-minute task which performs some action every 5 seconds.. This sounds pretty normal to me. After those 10 minutes the device should normally suspend your task and go to the Doze mode. It shouldn't allow you to execute this 5-second action infinitely.